# Revocation of intermediate trusted CA

Tags: certificate-revocation, ocsp, crl

My question is related to the revocation of intermediate CA. Suppose I have a device  that performs the revocation checks on the whole chain and assigns the intermediate CA's a trusted level.Now suppose one of those intermediate CA's got revoked, how would the device get to know about its revocation since it has already trusted it and would never throw an error. How is this handled in real world ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That intermediate CA's certificate should specify how revocation can be checked.  If the device performs revocation checks then it is going to access the CRL, use OCSP, or something similar.  That response should specify that the intermediate CA certificate was revoked.  Assuming the device processes this response appropriately it would no longer trust the intermediate CA certificate even if it was previously trusted.

In the real world a common problem is sometimes a device or software isn't designed to check for revocation at all.

Comment: {In the real world a common problem is sometimes a device or software isn't designed to check for revocation at all.}. What makes you say that? Not true.

Comment: Totally understood that. However if a device has assigned a trusted level to an intermediate CA, will it ever do revocation check on it again since it trusts the cert.

Comment: Yes @jatin it should do revocation checking (and expiration checking, subject name checking, etc.) every time it needs to use the cert.  I suppose a system could be designed to only check for revocation when adding the cert to the trusted store, but that seems unlikely and unwise.

Comment: @SandeepY It is true Sandeep.  It is getting better, but even just a couple years ago some [browsers didn't do revocation checking]( http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2014/04/24/certificate-revocation-why-browsers-remain-affected-by-heartbleed.html) on SSL/TLS certificates. Revocation checking is sometimes turned off because it causes performance delays that the app/device designer didn't want users to experience.